# get ANR on Asynk Task

Tags: java, android

i'm using Asynk Task for export data from db trough 4G network and in case of bad network connection i got ANR crash

```
  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FetchUrl fetchUrl=new FetchUrl();
    fetchUrl.execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            ExportData dataExchange = new ExportData(getApplicationContext());
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS", Locale.ENGLISH).format(currentTime);
            dataExchange.export_data(String.valueOf(format1).replace(":", "_"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

in function export_data data is export to ftp and mySQL server
here i set timout for ftp

```
 FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try {
                ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(2000);
                ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                ftpClient.setDataTimeout(2000);
                ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(2000);
```

and here i set timeout for mySql server

```
inal HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,3000);
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(strURL);
```

Comment: I think this needs more info. There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, the problem is somewhere else. Try to do more testing, are you sure it's the FetchUrl task that causes the ANR? If you don't execute it, does the problem get fixed? If so, we probably need to know what ExportData is doing. Please explore more and update the question. Thanks.

Comment: in function export_data data is export to ftp and mySQL server
here i set timout for ftp

                   ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                    ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(2000);
                    ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                    ftpClient.setDataTimeout(2000);
                    ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(2000);
and here i set timeout for mySql server
    httpParams=new BasicHttpParams()
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,3000);
                HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);